# Lang's Theorem 7.3 wording, what does he mean?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, proof-verification, proof-explanation, free-abelian-group

[image]

[image]

---

Above is the first part of proof Theorem 7.3, Lang's Algebra, p41.

**Why could we apply Lemma 7.2?** 
Isn't this only a consequence of this line? (Which was stated after application?)

> Since $f(B)$ is either $0$ or infinite cyclic...$B$ is free.

EDIT: I clarified question a bit.

Answer (score 1):

The free group on the empty set is $0$.
The free group on $\{g\}$ is the infinite cyclic group generated by $g$.

So in both cases considered $f(B)$ is free.

So $B_1$ is isomorphic to a restricted direct sum of copies of the group of integers because it is free by induction and abelian. Furthermore $\mathbb{Z}_1$ is not induced in this decomposition.

On the other hand $f(B)=C_1$ is isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}_1$ or $\{0\}$, so $B$ is isomorphic to a direct sum of copies of the group of integers, so $B$ is free.

Comment: I believe your $B_1$ and $C_1$ are reverse of the proof? (I will continue my question with the original one) So my problem is, in order to apply the lemma, we need the image of $f|B$ to be free, so we get that $C_1$ is free (from isomorphism) (or $B_1$ in your case). So the line I quoted was necessary?

Comment: you just needed $f(B)$ to be free and NOT generated by $x_1$ or $x_2$ and so on

Comment: Sorry, but I am now confused with what you mean by "not generated by $x_1$ or $x_2$... " may you elaborate? My understanding is: We obtain $B=B_1 \oplus C_1$ from lemma; all is required is that $f(B)$ is free.

Comment: Sorry I made a mistake I meant you need $f(B)$ not generated by $x_2, x_3 ...$ but it is obvious by definition of $f$. Indeed if $x_2$ for example was one of the generators of $f(B)$ then the sum would not necesarely be direct and you would not be able to conclude.

Comment: Do we need to check that though? All we need is image of $f$ to be free, then we can decompose $A = \ker f \oplus C$, where $C \cong Im f $ by lemma(?)

Comment: You don't need to check it but it is a part of the idea behind this lemma. This is what makes this lemma work

Comment: Ok, thanks a lot!